# how can i break a loop by checking a condition

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, char

I am trying to sum some integers and when I press '=' the loop will terminate and print the sum of those values. I am trying to give a space before press equal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, sum = 0;
    char b;

    while (1) {
        scanf("%d", &a);
        scanf(" %c", &b);

        sum += a;

        if(b == '=')
            break;
    }

    printf("sum = %d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whats your issue? Does it not break out of the loop when you press '='?

Comment: No, the problem is if I give input 1 2 3 4 it gives me sum= 7

Comment: You are doing scanf twice on the loop, that's why.

Comment: You need to learn to debug your code. Single-step through it using a debugger, or print out the variables in each iteration.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `scanf`, i.e.

```
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf(" %c", &b);
```

will work like this:

Input: "1 2 3 4 ="

In the first loop `a` will become 1 and `b` will become 2.

In the second loop `a` will become 3 and `b` will become 4.

Now the remaining string is " ="

So in the third loop there is no integer to scan and consequently `a` will still have the value 3. `b` will get the value `=` and the loop terminates.

So `sum` is 1 + 3 + 3, i.e. 7

You can check that using simple `printf` statements:

```
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("a=%d\n",a);
    scanf(" %c",&b);
    printf("b=%c\n",b);

Input:
1 2 3 4 =

Output:
a=1
b=2
a=3
b=4
a=3
b==
sum= 7
```

Remember: Always check the value returned by `scanf` - like:

```
if (scanf("%d",&a) != 1)
{
    // Error - didn't scan an integer
    // add error handling
    ...
}
```

So you can do

```
while(1){
    if (scanf("%d",&a) != 1)
    {
        // No integer found
        
        // Add error handling...
        // For now - just stop the loop
        break;
    }
    sum+=a;
}
```

For input like "1 2 3 4 =" this give the result 10.

However, input like "1 2 3 4 HelloWorld" will also give the result 10, i.e. any non-integer input simply terminates the loop. If you only want the loop to terminate when the input is `=`, you can extend the error-handling.

Comment: This is a great answer because, not only does it suggest an easy, standard, way to fix it, but it sheds light on why it behaves this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because you are doing scanf twice in your loop.

Do this instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int sum=0;
    char a[10];
    while(1){
        scanf("%9s", a); // makes sure we won't have memory overflow 
        if(strcmp(a, "=") == 0)
            break;
        sum+=atoi(a);
    }
    printf("sum= %d",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that only the 0th index is checked for an `=` input.

Comment: That's right, I kept it simple because I think @IshanAhmed is just looking for something that will sum the numbers properly. He can do the error handling, for potential invalid inputs.

Comment: The OP wants: *when I press '=' the loop will terminate and print the sum*.